# Laravel - Archiving Data, Delete and Insert to another Table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

When I click the button delete I want to delete the data and insert it to another table which is the archive how can I do it?

For e.g, my new another table model named **Archive** and new table named **archive**

Here is my Destroy Public Function:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $client = Client::find($id);
    $client->delete();

}
```

My Store Public Function:

```
$client = new Client;
$client->client_code = $request->input('client_code');
$client->client_name = $request->input('client_name');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So why don't you just softdelete them and use that as your archive. It will be easier to do operations like restore, get etc.

To softdelete the model needs

```
use SoftDeletes;
```

And in your migration table

```
$table->softDeletes();
```

Then when you run `$client->delete();` the model will only be marked as deleted and will not show up in queries
unless you use the `withTrashed()` in the query. And if you want it back you run `$client->restore()`;

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#soft-deleting

---

Or the solution you asked for

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $client = Client::find($id);

    Archive::create([
      'client_code' => $client->client_code,
      'client_name' => $client->client_name
    ])

    $client->delete();

}
```

Not sure how you will connect the archive data to the client if it has been removed, maybe have a user_id so you know who has what. Still recommend using softdeletes for this though.

Comment: umm.. I want to show my archives also will **SoftDeletes** will show my archives in another blade file? see I have to buttons **enable** and **disable** .. disable button archives my data but not delete it and store it to the archive.blade.php .. and enable button returns back my archive to the client.blade.php

Comment: If you just want delete and restore then you don't need `Archive` table you just `SoftDelete` it and when user enables back restore it back, You don't need to copy back and forth, you can restore deleted data using `Client::withTrashed()->find($client_id)->restore();`

Comment: Yes that works, if you use withTrashed or withOnlyTrashed you can show them in a separate blade.

Comment: @Marcus I've red the documenation. so in soft delete you dont need to create another table for archive am i right? just use the soft delete and your data will stay in your database even tho u deleted it in the website am i right?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Only if you use forceDelete(); the data will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way

```
public function archive()
{
    DeviceRawDataArchive::create($this->toArray());
    $this->delete();
}
```

and call in my controller like this

```
$rawData->archive();
```

Hope this helps someone. Soft delete is good but I'm dealing with millions of rows so it's best to archive them so my Cron Job runs faster.